# Hierarchical time series with multiplicative rather than additive relationship

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

The `hts` package by Prof. Hyndman is useful to compute GLS intervals for hierarchical time series. However, it assumes that the aggregated time series is always an additive combination of the disaggregated ones.

I want to forecast an aggregated data series which is the product combination of the disaggregated one (e.g.: sales = quantity * avg price). The solution that comes to mind is to predict the logs, transforming the relationship in an additive one, and then exponentiate back.

Is there a better way to do this using `hts`?

Comment: Don't think this question has anything to do with programming.

Comment: it is a question about a very specific R package.